# Actualice div en una parte de la página con jquery

Tags: jquery

Estoy tratando de actualizar un cierto div para que los pasos de compra se actualicen automáticamente. Para eso, lo estoy haciendo así:

```
<div class="how-it-work clearfix" id="atualizar">
      <?php echo $visualizar->visualizarEtapas($visualizarP->status_cart_order); ?>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
       $("#atualizar").load();
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

PHP funciona correctamente, el problema es con jquery. ¿Cómo hago que el div se actualice automáticamente?

Comment: a que te refieres con que se "actualice", que pretender hacer, llenar el div con contenido nuevo, ocultarlo? mostrarlo? cambiar el contenido que se nuestra por otro distinto.. deberias ser un ppoco mas especifico con lo que quieres hacer, tal vez mostrar la data que quieres poner en el div.. etc. Lectura recomendada [ask]

Comment: Hola David. Al actualizar el div, es para mostrar el contenido que existe en la variable PHP, donde se mostrará el paso de compra de la tienda online. Cada vez que un paso cambia al otro, aparece al usuario, sin necesidad de actualizar la página.